# Evaluating an integral with a modulus limit

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I evaluate this integral with a modulus?

$$\int_{|a-r|}^{a+r}(a^2+r^2-R^2)dR$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Evaluate 
$$\int_{t}^{a+r}(a^2+r^2-R^2)dR$$ as usual.

After which, substitute $t=|a-r|$.

In summary: there is nothing special about the modulus.